# cs50 pset4 filter "edges"

Tags: c, filter, cs50, edge-detection

When I run a photo through my `edges` code, the image is returned all white except for three rows of pixels at the bottom, which look similar to rainbow tv static. I've tried to debug my code, but I still cant figure it out:

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int gx[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
    int gy[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};
    int redx = 0;
    int greenx = 0;
    int bluex = 0;
    int redy = 0;
    int greeny = 0;
    int bluey = 0;
    int finalred = 0;
    int finalgreen = 0;
    int finalblue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            for (int k = i - 1; k <= i + 1 && k < height && k >= 0; k++)
            {
                for (int m = j - 1; m <= j + 1 && m < width && m >= 0; m++)
                {
                    if (k < i)
                    {
                        if (m < j)
                        {
                            redx += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gx[0][0];
                            greenx += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gx[0][0];
                            bluex += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gx[0][0];
                            redy += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gy[0][0];
                            greeny += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gy[0][0];
                            bluey += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gy[0][0];
                            // gx[?][0]
                        }
                        else if (m > j)
                        {
                            redx += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gx[0][2];
                            greenx += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gx[0][2];
                            bluex += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gx[0][2];
                            redy += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gy[0][2];
                            greeny += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gy[0][2];
                            bluey += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gy[0][2];
                            // gx[?][2]
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            redx += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gx[0][1];
                            greenx += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gx[0][1];
                            bluex += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gx[0][1];
                            redy += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gy[0][1];
                            greeny += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gy[0][1];
                            bluey += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gy[0][1];
                            // gx[?][1]
                        }
                        // gx[0][?]
                    }
                    else if (k > i)
                    {
                        if (m < j)
                        {
                            redx += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gx[2][0];
                            greenx += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gx[2][0];
                            bluex += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gx[1][0];
                            redy += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gy[2][0];
                            greeny += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gy[2][0];
                            bluey += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gy[2][0];
                            // gx[?][0]
                        }
                        else if (m > j)
                        {
                            redx += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gx[2][2];
                            greenx += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gx[2][2];
                            bluex += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gx[2][2];
                            redy += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gy[2][2];
                            greeny += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gy[2][2];
                            bluey += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gy[2][2];
                            // gx[?][2]
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            redx += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gx[2][1];
                            greenx += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gx[2][1];
                            bluex += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gx[2][1];
                            redy += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gy[2][1];
                            greeny += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gy[2][1];
                            bluey += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gy[2][1];
                            // gx[?][1]
                        }
                        // gx[2][?]
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (m < j)
                        {
                            redx += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gx[1][0];
                            greenx += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gx[1][0];
                            bluex += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gx[1][0];
                            redy += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gy[1][0];
                            greeny += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gy[1][0];
                            bluey += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gy[1][0];
                            // gx[?][0]
                        }
                        else if (m > j)
                        {
                            redx += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gx[1][2];
                            greenx += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gx[1][2];
                            bluex += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gx[1][2];
                            redy += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gy[1][2];
                            greeny += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gy[1][2];
                            bluey += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gy[1][2];
                            // gx[?][2]
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            redx += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gx[1][1];
                            greenx += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gx[1][1];
                            bluex += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gx[1][1];
                            redy += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gy[1][1];
                            greeny += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gy[1][1];
                            bluey += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gy[1][1];
                            // gx[?][1]
                        }
                        // gx[1][?]
                    }
                }
            }
            finalred = (redx)^2 + (redy)^2;
            finalgreen = (greenx)^2 + (greeny)^2;
            finalblue = (bluex)^2 + (bluey)^2;
            if (finalred > 255)
            {
                finalred = 255;
            }
            if (finalgreen > 255)
            {
                finalgreen = 255;
            }
            if (finalblue > 255)
            {
                finalblue = 255;
            }
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = finalred;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = finalgreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = finalblue;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Among other problems, you need to initialize the variables `redx` *et cetera* before starting the summations for each pixel, not once before the start of the loops.

Comment: You need to take the square root of the sum of the squares.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I changed what you said, but now the error message, `runtime error: -nan is outside the range of representable values of type 'int'` shows for lines `finalred = sqrt((redx)^2 + (redy)^2);`, `finalgreen = sqrt((greenx)^2 + (greeny)^2);`, and `finalblue = sqrt((bluex)^2 + (bluey)^2);`

Comment: When your pixel processing loop yields random garbage on one or more edges, your first hunch should be an edge condition, especially if you're working on a convolution kernel algorithm like edge detection. Without looking at your code, I advise looking for cases where you exceed the y limit and are convolving with pixels whose values are undefined. And if this is really the issue, then on some compilers you can expect to crash with a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) instead of displaying the results of processing undefined pixel values.

Comment: @Howlium my code no longer does that, now it just gives the error message, `runtime error: -nan is outside the range of representable values of type 'int'`

Comment: What do you think, this code does? `sqrt((greenx)^2 + (greeny)^2);` You should consult your C text book about operators. `^2` is not what you think it is.

Comment: `if (m < j)` What is your allowed range for `j`? What will be resulting range for `m`? Also all other similar checks will result in wrong ranges.

Comment: You didn't mention what kind of image is being worked with.   In any case, the `width` of pixels might not be the total width of each line due to the necessity that the number of bytes in each line MUST be a multiple of 4.  Have you done any checking of the image to assure that each pixel is 24 bits?

Comment: @Gerhardh Could you go more in depth about your second point, I don't really get it?

Comment: Do not remove original code from a question except to correct minor errors unrelated to the question. Stack Overflow is not a personal debugging service. Its goal is to be a durable repository of questions and answers for other people to learn from. The questions and answers need to be matched, and edit the code breaks that.

Comment: Eric already mentions this in his answer. Your loops and conditions are off by 1. If the range for `i` is `0..height-1` and `k` goes from `i-1..i+1`, you will end up with `k==-1` and `k==height` which is outside the valid range. Same for the other direction.

Comment: `image = newimage;` cannot work for two reasons: It only changes the local parameter `image`, not the caller’s pointer or array, and it would point to `newimage`, which is a local array that ceases to exist when the function returns. Break the problem into manageable pieces. Start by writing a function that simply creates a new array, fills it with all white, then puts those pixels in the original array. Test that. Then change it to all black. Test that. Then do only the pixels inside the array, ignoring those along the edges. Test that. Then do the edges, ignoring corners. Then corners.

Comment: You may need to reread lessons in the course. If you have new questions, enter a new question; do not alter this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Initialize Variables

These initializations:

```
    int redx = 0;
    int greenx = 0;
    int bluex = 0;
    int redy = 0;
    int greeny = 0;
    int bluey = 0;
```

appear before the `for` statements on `i` and `j`, but these variables accumulate sums for each pixel, so they must be initialized for each pixel. That is within the `for` statement on `j` and before the `for` statements on `k` and `m`.

(Since this was pointed out in a comment, the code in the question has been edited to assign zeros to these variables after updating each pixel. That works, but it is a poor solution. Simply move the definitions and initializations of the variables inside the outer two `for` loops.)

### Incorrect Loop Conditions

This statement will fail:

```
for (int k = i - 1; k <= i + 1 && k < height && k >= 0; k++)
```

Consider what happens when `i` is 0. Then `int k = i - 1` initializes `k` to −1. Then `k >= 0` is false, so the test `k <= i + 1 && k < height && k >= 0` is false, so the body of the loop is never executed, and none of the pixels in the row with `i`=0 are updated.

You need to rethink how the code is designed. This was apparently an attempt to handle edges and corners, which notionally involve calculations with pixels outside the array, but there are other solutions. This is a major point of this problem, so it would be a good exercise to think of and implement two or more solutions.

### Incorrect Operator

`^` is used to attempt exponentiation in `(redx)^2`. In C, `^` is an XOR operator. In this situation, to square a number, simply multiply itself, as with `redx*redx`. There is an exponentiation operator in C, but it is for floating-point arithmetic, so it is not suitable for this problem, and you will learn about it in another lesson.

### Premature Image Updates

These lines:

```
image[i][j].rgbtRed = finalred;
image[i][j].rgbtGreen = finalgreen;
image[i][j].rgbtBlue = finalblue;
```

are inside loops on `i` and `j`, so they update the image as each pixel is processed. These means pixels yet to be updated will use the new values assigned for previously updated pixels. This is incorrect; the original pre-updated values should be used when calculating values for new pixels. A solution for this requires using a separate buffer to hold new values temporarily. (An easy solution is to use a full separate array to hold the new values, but there are more space-efficient solutions.)

### Calculation Is Not Rounded

This code takes the square root and truncates it to an integer:

```
finalred = sqrt((redx)^2 + (redy)^2);
```

However, the [problem specification](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/filter/more/) says “And since channel values can only take on integer values from 0 to 255, be sure the resulting value is rounded to the nearest integer and

### Excessive Code

Code like this appears multiple times:

```
if (k < i)
                    {
                        if (m < j)
                        {
                            redx += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gx[0][0];
                            greenx += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gx[0][0];
                            bluex += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gx[0][0];
                            redy += image[k][m].rgbtRed * gy[0][0];
                            greeny += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gy[0][0];
                            bluey += image[k][m].rgbtBlue * gy[0][0];
                            // gx[?][0]
                        }
```

By the structure of these loops, `k` can only equal `i-1`, `i`, or `i+1`. Therefore, there is no need to use `if` statements to select index `0`, `1`, or `2`, of the arrays; we can simply calculate it, and similarly for `m`, and then one set of code suffices for all cases:

```
redx   += image[k][m].rgbtRed   * gx[k-(i-1)][m-(j-1)];
greenx += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gx[k-(i-1)][m-(j-1)];
bluex  += image[k][m].rgbtBlue  * gx[k-(i-1)][m-(j-1)];
redy   += image[k][m].rgbtRed   * gy[k-(i-1)][m-(j-1)];
greeny += image[k][m].rgbtGreen * gy[k-(i-1)][m-(j-1)];
bluey  += image[k][m].rgbtBlue  * gy[k-(i-1)][m-(j-1)];
```

Note that the problem of handling edges and corners still remains, per above.

### Unnecessary Initializations

These initializations and resets are unnecessary:

```
    int finalred = 0;
    int finalgreen = 0;
    int finalblue = 0;
```

```
            finalred = 0;
            finalgreen = 0;
            finalblue = 0;
```

Instead, just define these variables at the point where they are needed; change:

```
            finalred = sqrt((redx)^2 + (redy)^2);
            finalgreen = sqrt((greenx)^2 + (greeny)^2);
            finalblue = sqrt((bluex)^2 + (bluey)^2);
```

to:

```
            int finalred = sqrt((redx)^2 + (redy)^2);
            int finalgreen = sqrt((greenx)^2 + (greeny)^2);
            int finalblue = sqrt((bluex)^2 + (bluey)^2);
```

Defining variables just at the point where they are needed limits their scope, which limits opportunities to make mistakes with them. This applies to the `redx` and related variables above: By defining and initializing them within the per-pixel code, their use is restricted to computation for a single pixel, so the mistake of letting the sums accumulate over multiple pixels would have been impossible to make.

Comment: I changed the errors, but now when I run my code, it just pastes an unchanged image. My edited code is back in the original question.